# MySQL wrong results with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a table `user_comission_configuration_history` and I need to select the last Comissions configuration from a `user_id`.

Tuples:

[image]

I'm trying with many queries, but, the results are wrong. My last SQL:

```
SELECT *
    FROM(
        SELECT * FROM user_comission_configuration_history
        ORDER BY on_date DESC
    ) AS ordered_history
WHERE user_id = 408002
GROUP BY comission_id
```

The result of above query is:

[image]

But, the correct result is:

```
id    user_id    comission_id    value         type          on_date
24    408002     12              0,01          PERCENTUAL    2014-07-23 10:45:42
23    408002     4               0,03          CURRENCY      2014-07-23 10:45:41
21    408002     6               0,015         PERCENTUAL    2014-07-23 10:45:18
```

What is wrong in my SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: Yes, the response of Bill Karwin is correct and better performatic. On the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM user_comission_configuration_history
      ORDER BY on_date DESC
     ) AS ordered_history
WHERE user_id = 408002
GROUP BY comission_id;
```

One major problem with your query is that it uses a MySQL extension to `group by` that MySQL *explicitly* warns against.  The extension is the use of other columns in the in the`select` that are not in the `group by` or in aggregation functions.  The warning ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html)) is:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are **indeterminate**.

So, the values returned in the columns are **indeterminate**.

Here is a pretty efficient way to get what you want (with "comission" spelled correctly in English):

```
SELECT *
FROM user_commission_configuration_history cch
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from user_commission_configuration_history cch2
                  where cch2.user_id = cch.user_id and
                        cch2.commission_id = cch.commission_id and
                        cch2.on_date > cch.on_date
                 ) AND
      cch.user_id = 408002;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff, a very good response. But the results are still wrong. And change the second WHERE on cch.user_id to AND. Your SQL return 2 tuples and the correct number of tuples to user_id 408002 is 3.

Comment: The reason for 2 tuples instead of 3 I believe is due to the join on cch2.type.  I think it should be on comission_ID given desired results.  However the root cause of your problem being the indeterminate nature of the extended group by is dead on.

Comment: The root cause is ok to me now. Thanks!

Comment: @Maykonn . . . The answer should now be correct on both fronts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what your trying.  It gets the max date for each user_ID and commissionID and then joins this back to the base table to limit the results to just the max date for each commissionID.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_comission_configuration_history A
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT User_ID, Comission_Id, max(on_Date) mOn_Date
        FROM user_comission_configuration_history
        Group by User-Id, Comission_Id
    ) B
 on B.User_ID = A.User_Id
and B.Comission_Id = A.Comission_ID
and B.mOnDate=A.on_date
WHERE user_id = 408002
ORDER BY on_Date desc;
```